# POST 405 on Django admin auth

Tags: django, authentication, http-post, http-status-code-405

```
[18/Nov/2017 18:50:58] "GET /admin/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1637
Method Not Allowed (POST): /admin/login/
[18/Nov/2017 18:51:01] "POST /admin/login/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0
```

this used to work but now it doesn't. I tried to get another POST method working but couldn't. now I can't even log in. didn't change settings or anything. urls also look good. Django version 1.11.6

edit: urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^about/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='about.html')),
    url(r'^contact/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='contact.html')),
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html')),
    url(r'^feed/$', FeedView.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: can you provide code for urls ?

Comment: yeah I added it

Answer (score 0):

[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42464834/django-method-not-allowed-post)
Hard without seeing the code, but I guess there is a high chance that you are using the same URL for the two views (one for each post request).

Comment: yeah I've checked everything out. I'm not doing that